# Header for first tableview section is bigger than the rest

Tags: uitableview, swift, layout

I am making a custom uitableview.  However the header for the first section is bigger than the others.

Here is the code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    var header = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.width, 30))
    header.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 223/255.0, green: 170/255.0, blue: 128/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

    return header

}
```

[image: tableview screen shot]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you implement `- tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:` in your code?

Comment: No I have not I will try that.

Comment: I tried that and it works, thanks will select your answer in 4 minutes (stack exchange won't let me immediately select it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 30.0
    }
```